# If an infinite sum converges, the infinite integral must converge as well?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

Take a continuous function, $f(x)$ defined from from $1$ to $\infty$. Consider the integral:

$$I = \int\limits_1^\infty f(x) dx$$

And the sum:

$$S = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$$

Is it true that if $S$ converges then $I$ must converge as well? Or vice versa? If not, any counter-examples (with functional form of $f$)?

I guess $S>I$, so $I$ has to converge if $S$ converges but what about the other way around?

Comment: No. Make $f$ very large on  small intervals around the integers. Converse is obviuosly false. Also , a duplicate.

Comment: What's the other one its a duplicate of?

Comment: You can turn this into the integral test for sums if $f$ is positive and decreasing.

Comment: You're right, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

geetha290krm's comment is correct in that the answer is no; however, if you require $f$ to be monotone decreasing, it is true because you can bound the sum on both sides with the integral (though one of them will have shifted limits). In fact, *you don't even need continuity*! Monotone functions necessarily have at most countably infinitely many discontinuities (to see this, note that for a monotone function you can only have discontinuities of the first kind, that is, jump or hole discontinuities (where upper and lower limits exist) by the monotone convergence theorem for sequences. Now, at every discontinuity pick a rational number in the interval between the lowe and upper limit. Since it's monotone, this is an injection from the discontinuities to the rationals), which means they are continuous almost everywhere, which means they are (Riemann) integrable, and you can use the exact same integral-shifting-bkunding argument from before!